# Is it possible to get dotnet to produce a Windows and a Linux executable?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, .net-6.0

Building a .NET application via `dotnet build` produces a EXE file when building on Windows, and an ELF file when building on Linux. Specifying `RuntimeIdentifier` to `linux-x64` when building on Windows also produces an ELF binary. This is not a self contained application.

Is is possible to get `dotnet build` to produce both an EXE and an ELF file without having to build twice?

If not, since the application is not self contained the EXE/ELF file is just a thin wrapper `dotnet <app name>.dll`, is there a way to produce just the EXE/ELF without building the entire project?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it since who knows what problems a version mismatch could cause, but you could just take the EXE and the ELF file and add them to the folder after build.